# How to sign a document in xadesjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, sign

I have an issue regarding digital signatures and `xadesjs`. I am writing a small server in Node.js, which should encrypt an XML file with XAdES. I have a PFX file, which I exported to PEM and PK8 formats. The general issue is that when I generate the keyPair with `xadesjs`, everything is working fine. Here's an example:

```
// Generate RSA key pair
let privateKey, publicKey;
XAdES.Application.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        modulusLength: 1024, //can be 1024, 2048, or 4096,
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
        hash: { name: "SHA-256" }, //can be "SHA-1", "SHA-256", "SHA-384", or "SHA-512"
    },
    false, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
    ["sign", "verify"] //can be any combination of "sign" and "verify"
)
.then(function (keyPair) {
    privateKey = keyPair.privateKey;

    // Call sign function
    return SignXml(xmlString, privateKey, 
        { name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5", hash: { name: "SHA-256" } });
})
.then(function (signedDocument) {
    console.log("Signed document:\n\n", signedDocument);
    next(null, signedDocument);
})
.catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    next(e, null);
});
```

But I have been using probably all possible combinations to get the `importKey` method to work. For example this is not working, even though the key is in PKCS8 (exported with OpenSSL):

```
let key =  fs.readFileSync("key.pem");

XAdES.Application.crypto.subtle.importKey("pkcs8", key,
    {
        name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        modulusLength: 2048, //can be 1024, 2048, or 4096,
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
        hash: { name: "SHA-256" },
    },
    false, 
    ["sign"]
)
.then(function (privateKey) {
    // Call sign function
    return SignXml(xmlString, privateKey, 
         { name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5", hash: { name: "SHA-256" } });
})
```

I get an error that:

```
Error: ImportKey: Can not import key for pkcs8
```

My main goal is to get a program, where I could specify the path to the digital signature, and my program would import the Key and Certificate, and in the end sign my file with them. It would be comfortable if everything could be stored in a PFX file, but if you have any solution, even if the Key and Certificate are stored separately (PEM and PK8), I would be grateful.

Comment: I guess you are reading the key as pem. You need to import it as a binary ArrayBuffer: Remove the `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` header and footer, convert the content from base64 to binary, and transform the result from char to ArrayBuffer. Make sure your pkcs8 key is not protected by a password too

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody has the same issue. Here's an implementation with the help of @pedrofb 's answer.

First of all I get the key and certificate with the help of the `pem` npm package. Then I remove the header and footer and convert the key to an ArrayBuffer:

```
const pfx = fs.readFileSync("cert.pfx");
pem.readPkcs12(pfx, { p12Password: "test123" }, (err: any, cert: any) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    let privateKey = b64ToBinary(removePFXComments(cert.key));
    let certificate = removePFXComments(cert.cert);
```

and here's the implementation of the two used methods above:

```
function removePFXComments(pem) {
    let lines = pem.split('\n');
    let encoded = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].trim().length > 0 &&
            lines[i].indexOf('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----') < 0 &&
            lines[i].indexOf('-----END CERTIFICATE') < 0 &&
            lines[i].indexOf('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----') < 0 &&
            lines[i].indexOf('-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----') < 0 &&
            lines[i].indexOf('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----') < 0 &&
            lines[i].indexOf('-----END PUBLIC KEY-----') < 0 &&
            lines[i].indexOf('-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----') < 0 &&
            lines[i].indexOf('-----END PRIVATE KEY-----') < 0 &&
            lines[i].indexOf('-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----') < 0 &&
            lines[i].indexOf('-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----') < 0) {
            encoded += lines[i].trim();
        }
    }
    return encoded;
}

function b64ToBinary(base64) {
  let raw = atob(base64);
  let rawLength = raw.length;
  let array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

  for(let i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
    array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```